# Is there a 'screen pinning' or 'kiosk mode' available for the Google Tango?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-project-tango, kiosk-mode, android-screen-pinning

I am trying to activate "screen pinning" to lock access to a single app on the Google Tango, for public display purposes. I would like to do this WITHOUT an app from the Google Play store. Is there a "screen pinning" capability (as seen in Android Lollipop 5.0) available for the Google Tango's JellyBean-operated device? I have tried looking into the Security settings where android usually provides this tool/service, but cannot find it.

Comment: I don't think KitKat have "Screen Pinning" feature available. you may need to find third party solution. like below:   https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/2wvx7d/is_there_an_app_for_screen_pinning_for_kitkat/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think KitKat have "Screen Pinning" feature available. you may need to find third party solution. like below: https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/2wvx7d/is_there_an_app_for_screen_pinning_for_kitkat/